# Randomly selecting unique items from an array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I know that there have been a lot of similar questions and I went through most of them. The code that is closest to what I'm trying to achieve is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473095/pick-random-elements-from-an-array-without-repeating).
I have a list of people in each column (which represent a day). for the sake of this question let's assume it's 8 people in each column. I need to randomly select 5 unique people names. I've used splice() to delete the selected item from the array to make sure that it is not selected twice. I'm new to the coding and I think I'm doing some basic mistake as the splice works for the 1st loop and then the array goes back to the original one. Can you, please, help to identify my mistake?

```
for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
var sourceArray = ss.getRange(49,j+5,8,1).getValues();
var gg = Math.floor(Math.random()*sourceArray.length);
var pickedHLA = sourceArray[gg];
sourceArray.splice(gg, 1);
var HLAselect = ss.getRange(30+x,j+5,1,1)
HLAselect.setValue(pickedHLA);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `for` loop you are redefining the `sourceArray` during each iteration - you need to define this outside the loop, then do your work to randomly select and remove from the array:

```
var sourceArray = ss.getRange(49,j+5,8,1).getValues(); //establish full list of people

for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  var gg = Math.floor(Math.random()*sourceArray.length); //get random index
  var pickedHLA = sourceArray[gg];  //get random person via random index
  sourceArray.splice(gg, 1); //remove random person from full list of people
  var HLAselect = ss.getRange(30+x,j+5,1,1)
  HLAselect.setValue(pickedHLA);
}
```

Comment: `sourceArray.length - 0.1` in case `random` returned `1`

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this is actually quite simple, all it requires a few lines of code:

```js
var arr = ["Cheese", "Purple", "List", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
function random() {
  var randomNumber1 = parseInt(Math.random() * arr.length);
  var random = arr[randomNumber1];
  alert(random);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="random()">Click Me</button>
```

There you go!